# not able to find svn options in eclipse?

Tags: java, svn

I have imported a maven project. i did some modifications and need to check in. i have subclipse installed in my eclipse. but when i right click on the project, i could not find the options like commit, synchronize with repository..etc..

i am seeing only two options on right cliking on the project. they are :

```
Team ----> **apply patch** and **share project**
```

if i select share project, i am getting below error:

```
svn: The path 'D:\myproject_space' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
```

How can i get the other features?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use SVN 1.7 you will need to install Subclipse 1.8 by adding the following to your list of Update Sites: `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x`

Answer (score 2):

To support Subversion 1.7 and corresponding working copy format you need to install Subclipse 1.8.x. See Downloads tab on [Subclipse web site](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).